# How to remove Grub2?

Tags: grub2

I have a dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu with a custom boot-loader (long story).

My problem is that when I boot up, I get the choices for Windows and Ubuntu in my custom boot-loader, and if I choose Ubuntu, I then get GRUB, with a working Linux entry and a bunch of other entries that don't really make sense.

So basically what I am trying to do is completely remove GRUB, and just use my custom boot-loader. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

No need to remove grub. (I don't know whether its possible).Sometime you may require to boot into  recovery mode/ older kernel. GRUB comes handy in that case.

Try

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value to 0. (value in second)

save, now run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Once done, grub screen won't show. Now to get grub. You just need to press <kbd>shift</kbd> while booting.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom bootloader is also some version of grub, then try shorting the path by putting appropriate booting parameter, and if not, then keep using as it is, because initrd is invoked by grub, and you can use any other bootloader only if it supports booting linux.

Comment: Custom bootloader may not be grub. There are so many boot loaders. Even windows boot loader can be used to boot linux.